# Avoid intermediate directories in VC++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, build

I'm maintaining a build script that calls devenv or Incredibuild from the command line to build a dynamically generated Visual C++ 2010 solution made up of several hundred projects.  We're looking into ways of improving our build and I was wondering if there was a way to tell VS to avoid using intermediate directories.

For example, say I have a project `Foo` in a solution `Bar`.  When I build `Bar`, the output from `Foo` ends up both in `Bar/Foo/$(Configuration)/$(Platform)` and in `Bar/$(Configuration)/$(Platform)`.

I'd like to know if there's a way (from the command line or by editing project files) to make devenv build directly in the solution's output directory and only there.  Also, are there any reasons why I should/shouldn't do such a thing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply set the intermediate directory path in the .vcxproj files to the same as the solution output directory.

Assuming your projects don't have the same output filename as each other there is no problem mixing intermediate directories. You can also set it to create all the intermediate directories under TEMP or on another drive.

Comment: Do I risk running into problems if I set my build up like that and would I end up with intermediate junk in the final output folder?

Answer (score 4):

DONT do that!!!!
since there is a bug (I call this behaviour a bug) in MSBuild that when you do a rebuild of a project, all files of ALL projects that use the same Intermediate Directory will be deleted in the
output folder before the project is Build...

Comment: how to avoid MSBuild to clean up this intermediate directory? is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Yes, I agree this is a bug. Because even if Win32 and x64 have different output directories. But if they use the same intermediate directory, when clean/rebuild any platform, both output directory would be cleaned. To avoid that, use $(Platform) variable in intermediate directory setting.